# Solving the system of equations $13p-92q = 273, 12p-91q = 273$ by a smart approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't see how to make this problem simpler so I can avoid fractions or big number arithmetic.
I understand we can always find a $p$ and $q$ to satisfy either equation independently but because but coefficients are $1$ apart and the equations totaling the same value, I'm suspicious if there is actually a solution.

$\begin{align} 
13p - 92q = 273 \\
12p - 91q = 273 \\
\end{align}$

I'm trying to solve this using substitution.

Comment: one may subtract equations

Comment: So use elimination? Ok, I will look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can always subtract equations
$$ \begin{align*} 
13p - 92q = 273 \\
12p - 91q = 273 \\
\end{align*} $$
to discover that $$p - q = 0 \Longrightarrow p = q$$ and so by substituting one for the other we can find that
$$ 13p - 92q = -79p = 273 \Longrightarrow p = q = \frac{-273}{79} $$